# Migrating Domain Users to another Domain

Tags: active-directory, domain, user-profiles, xcopy

I have a kiosk user on which many workstations are logged in currently. I am working on a project to move everyone from Kiosk to their own domain user so instead of using kiosk user called USER I want to deploy their `FirstName.LastName` user.

I am working on a PC now, which has tons of files, directories, emails etc (outlook using POP3 which has a tons of folders for his emails and rules.)

I would like to copy `Desktop`, `Docs`, `Favorite` and `Etc`.

Doing this using batch script would save so much time.
Without script, this would take hours and hours.
So any help and insight knowledge would be appreciated.
Is there a way to have the script read what user I am logged in as -- which in this case would be domainname/user -- and have it moved to domainname/john.doe?

Please help and thank you so much. So far I have used below

```
xcopy /E /Y C:\Users\john.doe "\\server\Backup xcopy\%COMPUTERNAME%XCOPY" /MIR
```

However when I have /E /I /Y it didn't worked as expected. So I ran the command without I. It copied many things but here are what it missed. Since we use Thunderbird, Outlook, or Windows Live Mail, I need to be able to copy and mirror entire App Data but it doesn't copy that at all. So how can I get that and also how to add text doc after it finishes the command on the File itself to show what it copied and what it missed.

XcopyResult:

[image]

As you can see on the Picture, its missing entire Directory of AppData which is what I need the most if I want to copy folders such as Google Chrome data, email data and such.

Let me know

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to transfer all the local files of one user to a new one you created?

Comment: No opposite. I have a domain user called "dc-user" and I want to move all files from that user to a new domain user for that workstation. So move all stuff from domainname/dc-user to domainname/john.doe user which will also be on same domain. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Close voters: ServerFault doesn't want a request for script/software any more than Super User does.

Comment: @ABITSupport Welcome to Super User. What have you tried? What research have you done? Please edit this into your question.

Comment: I have used xcopy to just copy from local machine to local machine but beside that I haven't used anything for Domain users. And I just inputted commands in with xcopy but later today I can create a batch script and post it here. Sorry I was in a rush and that's why I just inputted my question.

Comment: @Twisty Here is what I am using xcopy /E /Y C:\Users\john.doe "\\server\Backup xcopy\%COMPUTERNAME%XCOPY" /MIR (However when I have /E /I /Y it didn't worked as expected. So I ran the command. It copied many things but here are what it missed. Since we use Thunderbird, Outlook, or Windows Live Mail, I need to be able to copy and mirror entire App Data but it doesn't copy that at all. So how can I get that and also how to add text doc after it finishes the command on the File itself to show what it copied and what it missed

Comment: Please edit this info into your question.

Comment: You can't migrate user profiles just by copying the user's profile folder...

Comment: @Twisty I you mean by xcopying the entire Profile directory. I might but not sure if it would copy other files as I needed. I just found out Appdata was hidden files so it wouldn't copy from Xcopy so is there a switch I could use to force copy following: Desktop, My Doc, Favorite, AppData/Local and Roaming etc.

Comment: One problem with copying a user's entire profile directory is that you'll specifically have problems copying the `AppData/Local and Roaming` folders. These usually contain files with long filenames, odd security permisions, etc. Further, much of the data in these folders won't work on another machine without the proper Registry entries.  You're better off copying specific data that you need out of the `AppData` folder structure.

Comment: I will probably try copying entire directory of the profile and see if that works. Thanks @Twisty